# How can I save a option from multi select in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I have a modal with a single select called "Impacto OEE" that has 3 options "Queda de Disponibilidade", "Queda de Performance" and "Nenhum". If the option chosen by the user is "Queda de Disponibilidade" it will be saved as "Disponibilidade", if it is "Queda de Performance" it will be "Performance" and if it is "Nenhum" it will be "Nenhum". But when I click on register it is only saved as "Disponibilidade" or "Nenhum". In my database (PostgreSQL) the column is called "impact_oee" as ENUM with values "Disponibilidade, "Performance", "Nenhum".

I'm new to Angular, but I don't understand what I should do to make it work correctly, or what am I doing wrong. Below are parts of the code. Can someone help me?

Here is my code in HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <isteven-multi-select directive-id="impactos" tabindex="4" class="multiselect" helper-elements="filter"
                          translation="traducaoMultiSelect"
                          input-model="impactos"
                          output-model="impacto"
                          button-label="name"
                          item-label="name"
                          tick-property="ticked"
                          ng-class="{'open':impactosOpen }"
                          on-open="impactosOpen = true"
                          on-close="impactosOpen = false"
                          selection-mode="single" />
</div>
```

MultiSelect Config:

```
$scope.impactos = [{ name: "Queda de Disponibilidade" }, { name: "Queda de Performance" }, { name: "Nenhum" }]
```

Where do I get the data from my server:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    restApi.motivosParadaGerenciamento.query({}, function (array) {
                        $scope.motivos = [];
                        if (array.length > 0) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                                $scope.motivos.push({
                                    id: array[i].id,
                                    ...

                                    impactos: array[i].impacto_oee,

                                    ...
                                });
                            }
                        }
```

My register function:

```
function cadastrar () {
    restApi.gerenciamentoMotivosParada.save({
        ...
        impacto_oee: $scope.selectedUnique($scope.impactos) === "Queda de Disponibilidade" ? "Disponibilidade" : "Queda de Performance" ? "Performance" : "Nenhum",
    }, ...
}
```

I have an update function that is used in the editing part that also doesn't work when I select "Nenhum". The "Nenhum" option is simply ignored.

```
function atualizar () {
    var motivo;
    if ($scope.editing >= 0) {
        motivo = {
            ...         
            impacto_oee: $scope.selectedUnique($scope.impacto) === "Queda de Disponibilidade" ? "Disponibilidade" : "Queda de Performance" ? "Performance" : "Nenhum" ? "Nenhum" : "Nenhum"
           ...
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in your register function. Correct way to write it is as follows

```
function cadastrar () {
    restApi.gerenciamentoMotivosParada.save({
        ...
        impacto_oee: ($scope.selectedUnique($scope.impactos) === "Queda de Disponibilidade") ? "Disponibilidade" : ($scope.selectedUnique($scope.impactos) === "Queda de Performance") ? "Performance" : "Nenhum",
    },
    ...
}
```

> **Explanation:**

Basically what you are trying to achieve using Ternary Operator is `if-elseif-else`

```
if (condition1) {
    //value1
} else if(condition2) {
    //value2
} else {
    //value3
}
```

in your case, `condition2` was missing, that is the reason, it was not checking "Queda de Performance" condition

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem to be working as I imagined. Now regardless of options it is just saved as "Nenhum"

Comment: can you check if right value is returned from $scope.selectedUnique($scope.impactos) function?

Comment: Shure, I did a `console.log($scope.selectedUnique($scope.impactos))` and what is shown is  `"Queda de Disponibilidade"`, even if I choose one of the other options.. I am a little confuse.

Comment: I added one more thing to my question, if you could take a look... :)

Comment: very strange behavior, what does $scope.selectedUnique() function do? can you share the snippet of it?

Comment: Also, I see you are using $scope.impactos in cadastrar() and $scope.impacto in atualizar(). The selected value will be present in $scope.impacto which is the output model

Comment: The function $scope.selectedUnique: `$scope.selectedUnique = function (output) {
   var value = output && output[0] && output[0].name ? output[0].name : "-";
   return value;
  };`  This is just to show the option chosen in editing mode.

Comment: "Also, I see you are using $scope.impactos in cadastrar() and $scope.impacto in atualizar(). The selected value will be present in $scope.impacto which is the output model" I'm not sure I understand the problem with that very well. Can you explain better?

Comment: When I go to edit and select "Nenhum" in my console under "networks" this appears to me: `..
impacto_oee: "Performance"
..` If my previous option was "Queda de Performance". Queda de Performance and Queda de Disponibilidade are working fine, but the "Nenhum" option is not. (In case of editing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239133/discussion-between-nikhil-amin-and-akhaz).